# Interpret ISO week-of-year in gnu coreutils

Tags: date, gnu-coreutils

Gnu `date` is usually pretty flexible with input to its `--date` option. However I find it is not giving me expected results using the ISO-8601 format for week-of-year that I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), namely `yyyy-'W'ww` or `yyyy-'W'ww-d`:

```
$ date -d 2019-W14-2  # expect some variation on 2019-04-02
date: invalid date '2019-W14-2'
```

Is there any format with which I can ask `date` to tell me about the 14th week of 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked the relevant code down to [`gnulib`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) module `parse-datetime`. It looks like this would have to be a new feature. I'll update this space if it's ever implemented.